# Mix between Gnome 2 menu an Unity possible?

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher

I very much like the old Gnome 2 menu style Ubuntu used to have before switching to Unity. Still, I like many of the new Unity features, too! Meanwhile though I've been using Ubuntu in many different ways with many different programs installed. If you have only a few programs in use, you can easily keep them in an orderly way within the launcher on the left side, but if you have many programs (i.e. +20) installed, this one bar just won't do a good job, because it tries to squeeze all them to this left bar area. The Ubuntu opened with the super-key is an alternative way, where you can find all your programs by typing the application name, but when you have many programs installed it can happen that you know what program you wanted to use, but you just cannot remember the name. Searching for it in this Ubuntu menu can be quite cumbersome. The old style menu was fantastic for this. Every program was categorised in Graphics, Office, Programming, etc. I found it always very easy to use.

Is there any addon or plugin for Unity to get back this old style categorised menu? It'd be nice to have that without having to change to another desktop environment.

Comment: Why don't you use [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)?

Comment: @mikewhatever I like Unity and the way you search for programs and set the settings of multiple screens. Mate is very reduced in that manner. I'm really just looking for a way to customize the regular Unity and add this category style menu we were all used to back in the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get Unity to show programs in categories. If you have only problems putting many programs into the left bar, you can shrink the buttons there (using Unity Tweak Tool).

Otherwise, you can use Cinnamon instead of Unity to have most of the applets and searches and still retain the menu with programs ordered in categories.

Another possibility is using Cairo Dock. It adds a bottom bar that has programs listed in categories, in other features it's mostly similar to Mac.

Comment: Sad to hear, but regettably seems correct. Thx